# How to plot multiple barplot with different Y and the same X?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataset and I want to find out how several columns values (numeric values) differ across two different groups (`'group'` is a column that takes either the value of `'high'` or `'low'`).

I want to plot several barplots using a similar system/aesthetics to Seaborn's `FacetGrid` or `PairGrid`. Each plot will have a different Y value but the same X-axis (The group variable)

This is what I have so far:

```
sns.catplot(x='group', y='Number of findings (total)',  kind="bar",
            palette="muted", data=df)
```

But I would like to write a loop that can replace my `y` variable with different variables. How to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a stacked-barchart or a clustered barchart?

Comment: Each Y variable would be on a different Y axis. Here a link that gives an idea of the aesthetics, however I would like to have the same variable on the X axis (group) and different Y axis for different variables (and of course, all of them barplots)  https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html